# Is there a shorter notation for properties in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, properties

I'm usually programming in C# but also in the old language Delphi. In Delphi, for as far as I know, a property uses a lot of code like so:

```pascal
private
  FOPPORTUNITY_NR   : string;

  procedure SetOPPORTUNITY_NR(const aOPPORTUNITY_NR: string);
  function  GetOPPORTUNITY_NR: string;

public
  property  OPPORTUNITY_NR: string read GetOPPORTUNITY_NR write SetOPPORTUNITY_NR;

implementation

procedure TTypeName.SetOPPORTUNITY_NR(const aOPPORTUNITY_NR: string);
begin
  if (SpecialStrUtils_13.IsBlankStr(aOPPORTUNITY_NR)) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('OPPORTUNITY_NR cannot be empty');

  FOPPORTUNITY_NR := aOPPORTUNITY_NR;
end;

function TTypeName.GetOPPORTUNITY_NR: string;
begin
  if (SpecialStrUtils_13.IsBlankStr(FOPPORTUNITY_NR)) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('OPPORTUNITY NUMBER not set');

  Result := FOPPORTUNITY_NR;
end;
```

In C# I can write the code above like so:

```cs
private string? _opportunityNr = null;

public string OpportunityNr 
{ 
    get => _opportunityNr ?? throw new Exception("Opportunitynr not set");
    set => _opportunityNr = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? throw new Exception("Opportunitynr can not be empty") : value;
}
```

Is there a shorter notation in Delphi like in C#?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That is sad. Delphi code is so bloated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps the downvoters feel that you could have found the answer yourself by reading [the official documentation on properties](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)).

Comment: C# is also old compared to newer languages. What's the short notation for inline assembler code in C# (implying it's even possible)?

Comment: @AmigoJack what's the relevance of inline assembler?

Comment: I find Pascals 'verbosity' to be quite useful. It is just really easy to read and understand. Sure, other languages get shorter code, but are not really easier to read - especially for beginners.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I compared one specific criteria with another specific one (which I freely chose): C# has shorter notation, but lacks inline assembler. I wanted to point out that "_old language Delphi_" has by far not only disadvantages over C# and may have essential features that "newer" languages miss or cannot support by design.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I did read before I asked the question and didn’t find a shorter version either. But there are so many tricks possible that are not documented. Just wanted to learn from experienced Delphi developers.

Comment: Most of us are likely to get old and die before syntactically-nice stuff is added to Delphi that has been in other languages for over a decade. This is one of many examples. Most of the "tricks" you refer to aren't in the syntax, but use of classes. Perhaps when nullable pointers / references are added to the language, some of this syntactic sugar will be thrown in as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a shorter notation in Delphi like in C#?

No.

Comment: One reason is: in Pascal/Delphi there's no [ternary operator (only a workaround)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:#Delphi).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use methods:

```
property  OPPORTUNITY_NR: string read FOPPORTUNITY_NR write FOPPORTUNITY_NR;
```

Comment: I know that. I over simplified the code. Let me introduce some more code.